# Reset permissions on physical device

Tags: bixby

In Bixby Simulator we can reset the User Profile Access permission using the checkbox under permissions.  How do I reset the permission on a physical device for testing?  I didn't see a solution mentioned in the docs for on-device testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset permissions and linked OAuth accounts using Bixby Studio. Log in with the same developer account you used when you enabled "on-device testing" on your Samsung device. Then, with the capsule open in the IDE, open the simulator, start a conversation, and go to the Settings tab (icons on the left of the simulator). Ensure that you reset Selection Learning and remove OAuth and other permissions, if shown. (Refer to the screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: My understanding is that after reset on IDE (using the revision id number), on-device testing should also be reset.